# What converge test can I use for this series?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

What test can I use to show that this series diverges or converges?

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\sinh{\frac{1}{n}}}$

The integral test fails, since I can't integrate this function. The ratio test and the root test fails to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sinh x}{x} =1$$
so you can use comparision test to see that the series diverges.

Comment: This was easier than I thought... thanks!

Comment: I see that one could also do $\lim{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sinh{\frac{1}{x}}}{\frac{1}{x}}$

Answer (score 1):

Prove that $\sinh(x)\ge x$ for $x\ge 0$

Comment: Thanks! This did it.